# OverconstrainedError when requesting speakers stream via getUserMedia in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium, html5-audio, getusermedia, web-mediarecorder

Please consider the code below:

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then(function() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((devices) => {
        devices.forEach(function(device1, k1) {
            if (device1.kind == 'audiooutput' && device1.deviceId == 'default') {
                const speakersGroupId = device1.groupId;
                devices.forEach(function(device2, k2) {
                    if (device2.groupId == speakersGroupId && ['default', 'communications'].includes(device2.deviceId) === false) {
                        const speakersId = device2.deviceId;
                        const constraints = {
                            audio: {
                                deviceId: {
                                    exact: speakersId
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        console.log('Requesting stream for deviceId '+speakersId);
                        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then((stream) => { // **this always fails**
                            console.log(stream);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The code asks for permissions via the first `getUserMedia`, then enumerates all devices, picks the default audio output then tries to get a stream for that output.

But it will always throw the error: `OverconstrainedError { constraint: "deviceId", message: "", name: "OverconstrainedError" }` when getting the audio stream.

There is nothing I can do in Chrome (don't care about other browsers, tested Chrome 108 and 109 beta) to get this to work.

I see a report [here](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-main/issues/629#issuecomment-545953051) that it works, but not for me.

Please tell me that I'm doing something wrong, or if there's **another way** to get the speaker stream that doesn't involve chrome.tabCapture or chrome.desktopCapture.

Chrome MV3 **extension ways are welcomed**, not only HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

`.getUserMedia()` is used to get input streams. So, when you tell it to use a speaker device, it can't comply. gUM's error reporting is, umm, confusing (to put it politely).

To use an output device, use [element.setSinkId(deviceId)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/setSinkId). Make an audio or video element, then set its sink id. Here's the MDN example; it creates an audio element. You can also use a preexisting audio or video element.

```js
const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
const audioDevice = devices.find((device) => device.kind === 'audiooutput')
const audio = document.createElement('audio')
await audio.setSinkId(audioDevice.deviceId)
console.log(`Audio is being played on ${audio.sinkId}`)
```

Comment: So how can this redirect be used to record flat tab audio?